# Can weight shift control aircraft be used commercially?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa

Can a WSC aircraft registered SLSA be used commercially i.e., local tours for hire?
FAA regulations do not seem to address a commercial rating for WSC.

Comment: I know nothing about WSC but what would happen if passenger shift his weight in undesirable position?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about LSAs, but the regulations say that LSAs with a special airworthiness certificate may not be used in commercial operations (with two exceptions).

[This FAA document](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/gen_av/light_sport/media/LSA_Cert_8July2013.pdf) says that a weight-shift-control LSA will have a special airworthiness certificate:

> A special airworthiness certificate in the light-sport category is
>   issued to an aircraft that meets the definition of light-sport
>   aircraft (LSA), is manufactured to the applicable consensus standards,
>   and is one of the following five classes of the LSA category:
>   airplanes, gliders, powered parachutes, weight-shift-control aircraft
>   (commonly called trikes), and lighter-than-air aircraft (balloons and
>   airships).

And [14 CFR 91.327](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1327) says:

> (a) No person may operate an aircraft that has a special airworthiness
>   certificate in the light-sport category for compensation or hire
>   except—
>
> (1) To tow a glider or an unpowered ultralight vehicle in accordance
>   with §91.309 of this chapter; or
>
> (2) To conduct flight training.

Comment: I am by no means familiar with all LSAs, but the thought of using a powered parachute, WSC/trike or balloon to tow another... anything... is somewhere between amusing and terrifying!

Answer (score 0):

All commercial operations require a pilot who holds a commercial or ATP certificate with appropriate ratings at a commercial level or higher.

There is no provision in the FARs to give pilots a commercial WSC rating.